# What is the name of this disease, it's cause and cure?

Tags: sleep

I suffer from the following condition:

Mainly in the rainy season sometimes from being asleep I wake up. But neither I am able to open my eyelids, nor move any body part. But I am fully conscious. I struggle to move my fingers. After a few minutes with extreme effort and associated unbearable pain I am finally able to move my body parts and open my eyelids. Why this takes place and what is the cure?

NOTE: My maternal grandmother and mother also suffer from this condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likely it's [sleep paralysis](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleep_paralysis) in the [hypnopompic state](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypnopompic). It's not uncommon and has a hereditary component. Drug therapy is not that useful, and it may just require some cognitive therapy.